# Resizing content to fit height CSS overflowing?

Tags: html, css, height

I feel like going nuts, if `height: 100%;` stretches an element to fit its parent height why does it overflow? i'm testing in several browsers and all of them show the same problems.

i have this structure

```
html
>body
>>container
>>>header
>>>content
>>>footer
```

what i want is to stretch content height so container fits into browser window

i tried a ton of different approaches, making html and body height 100%, going for absolute and top and bottom of zero... and nothing really works, whenever i stretch content the footer jumps out of the container

here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
#container 
{
 height: 100%;
}
#content 
{
min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
1
</div>
<div id="content">
2
</div>
<div id="footer">
3
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

what is wrong with this, why is it going out?

Comment: you give your container a height of 100%. Then you add the divs. Your content div has also a height of min 100%. So, all divs together are definitiv bigger then the container and overflow. your content-height messes it up

Comment: this is just one of the examples i tried, i need to let the container stretch for the content, and i do that by saying it occupies 100% of the space, how do i say for the content to occupy the remaining space?

Comment: then just make a fixed positioned footer and give the content a margin-bottom with the height of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves your problem.  the inside divs needs to add up to 100%

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#container  
{ 
    height: 100%; 
} 
#header{
    height: 20%;  /*random number  but all three should add up to 100%*/
}
#content  
{ 
    min-height: 70%; /*random number*/
} 

#footer{
    height:10%; /*random number*/
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work because both header and footer have a fixed height for my case since their content doesn't change, it's the content of.. content that changes and i want it to grow when the screen in bigger than the content